# GCP Bigquery Storage write API (Protobuf) input error (float value 0 changes to null)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am having some issues with the Bigquery Storage write API,
When I append value 0 to the row it changes to nan value when it get imported to BQ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt7jP.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.